# VideoPlayer is cut in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have modeled a semicircular television and assigned a VideoPlayer to the screen in Unity to play videos.
The problem is that the videos are cut to the right.
Any idea what this problem could be due to?

Comment: What does the inspector for the screen look like? I assume you're using a RenderTexture with the VideoPlayer? Are you using an imported asset as the video? What should the full frame look like? It seems just to be that the aspect ratios are off.

Comment: Yes I'm using a render Texture for the videoplayer. Video is an .mp4 imported asset. 
The subtitles and texts that appear in the video should not be cut off to the right! How could I activate the aspect ratios? I'm trying with this code line but video doesn't change.  myVideo.aspectRatio = VideoAspectRatio.FitInside;

Comment: It may have to do with the texture mapping for the screen model, since the `RenderTexture` is still mapped onto the model like any other texture. What does the model of your screen look like? Is its UV mapping correct? You can also try playing around with the the Video Player's "Aspect Ratio" property *in the inspector itself*, to see if it changes anything. If it has to do with mismatched aspect ratios, there should be some kind of visible change in the Scene viewport; otherwise, it's probably something else causing the problem.